# Android fragment sidebar

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I have a small sidebar fragment that I add upon action item selection.  It has a fixed width and my desire is that the main view will appear full screen until action item selection when it will be slightly compressed to allow the sidebar to appear.

I've tried quite a few things including relative toleftOf/RightOf and various layout/width combinations.  I always end up with the sidebar taking the full screen unless I use a LinearLayout with weights.  The problem with the semi-working LinearLayout weight is that it uses a % of the screen which causes unreliable effects on different screen sizes.

Has anyone pulled off something similar?

```
 ______    _
|      |  | |
| Main |<-|S|
|______|  |_|
```

Currently semi-working xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- This will initially have no content/collapsed -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="4" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment xml (could be a fixed width):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout />

    <Button />

    <Button />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment addition:

```
// This should just push the frame layout the necessary width to display the fragment
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutEdit, xmpFrag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set a weight on the sidebar; set a fixed size (or wrap_content) and set the layout_width of the main content to 0dp.

Depending on the effect you want, you may want to put them both in a FrameLayout so the sidebar overlays the main fragment instead of shrinking the main fragment, make the main fragment always fill and the sidebar just be its own size.

Comment: Due to the orientaiton of some elements I didn't want an overlay.  This worked with some modifications.

Main
1. layout_width: 0dp
2. layout_weight: 1
Sidebar:

Comment: (Got locked out of finishing the comment edit)
This worked with some modifications.

Main FrameLayout
1. layout_weight: 1
Note: layout_width: 0dp requires weight, but doesn't change anything
Sidebar FrameLayout:
1. layout_width: wrap_content
2. NO WEIGHT
Sidebar:
1. layout_width: 300dp
Note: 300 is arbitrary for your content, wrap_content caused it to never show

Comment: Is your sidebar a custom view? If so, you should override onMeasure to allow the wrap_content to work.

Comment: If you want to see a full example including animating the sidebar sliding in/out, take a look at http://javadude.com/misc/slide-from-right-example.zip. (I thought it would be fun to try it...)

Comment: That's good stuff.  One thing to note your example is an overlay, so not exactly what I had in mind.  However I wasn't aware of the hide/show fragment capability.  That may very well be better if I can get it to work in a non-overlay manner.  I'm playing with a redesign now.

Comment: Good luck! (I suspect it'll work pretty much as-is with your layout)

Comment: It required a significant redesign, but that was due to how rigidly I was following the add/remove design, including that the xml contained only an empty wrapper for the fragment (it isn't shown by default).  With the show/hide I added the fragment directly to the xml so I actually get WYSWYG which is a huge improvement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual working code to the above answer (thanks Scott for helping me make the logical leap):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>

<!-- This will initially have no content/collapsed -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" >

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout />

    <Button />

    <Button />

</RelativeLayout>
```